# Google Drive API Channel not receiving notification after file being modified in shared folder

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have an active google drive channel (that i renew every day in order to maintain an active channel) to receive notifications when files are being modified inside a shared folder. The channel is set to watch that folder, but when someone makes a modification in a file inside that folder i don't receive a notification on that channel **until** i manually open that shared folder in my web browser.

Is there a way to request a refresh or something on that shared folder in order to receive the notifications when someone makes a modification?

Comment: Please provide your sample code so we can further help [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)